# A word or a phrase to describe a person pushing her luck

Tags: word-request, phrase-usage

A colleague of mime encounter a person who keep on pushing her luck even though my colleague have been giving her too much leeway.

Is there a word or a phrase to describe such person?

Answer (score 1):

"**Keep on pushing her luck**" may be close to the definition of "**Pester**" which defines as " to try to persuade someone by asking them something several times ", according to Longman Dictionary.  Add an "er" and you can call him a "**Pesterer**".

"**Keep pushing her luck**" could also be construed as someone who is trying to take advantage as much as possible from a person or situation, and the adjectival word to describe someone as that is **exploitative**.